# How to Prevent Injection Attacks in a NoSQL Database like GridDB?

Tags: .net, griddb, nosql-injection

Developing applications on .NET helps you provide a sense of security since it supports various built-in functions for SQL-based databases. I have been using SQL Server as a database for my
project, but it has limitations like its limited horizontal scalability, while NoSQL offers you horizontal scalability. Therefore, I am using [GridDB](https://docs.griddb.net/about/what-is-griddb/#high-performance), which is known for its high performance and scalability.

However, I am afraid about the security risk of NoSQL databases. In my project, I used the Dependency Injection Service offered by .NET to prevent SQL injection attacks, as shown in the
[.NET Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

I tried to enact in my code as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using EmployeeManagementDAL.Interface;
using EmployeeManagementDAL;

namespace EmployeeManagementBL
{
    public static class Injection
    {
        public static void DependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection service)
        {
            service.AddTransient<EmployeeRepoInterface, EmployeeRepo>();
        }
    }
}
```

Following is an instance of `addEmployee(Employee emp)` function to add employees using .NET `parameter.Add()` function in SQL database as follows:

```cs
public void addEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@Name", emp.Name, DbType.String);
    parameters.Add("@Designation", emp.Designation, DbType.String);
    parameters.Add("@Department", emp.Department, DbType.String);

    string output_query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] (Name, Designation, Department) VALUES (@Name, @Designation, @Department);";
    IDbConnection connection = null;

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        connection.Query<Employee>(output_query, parameters);
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Following is an instance of `addEmployee(Employee emp)` function to add employees using .NET `parameter.Add()` function in SQL database as follows:

```cs
public void addEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@Name", emp.Name, DbType.String);
    parameters.Add("@Designation", emp.Designation, DbType.String);
    parameters.Add("@Department", emp.Department, DbType.String);

    string output_query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] (Name, Designation, Department) VALUES (@Name, @Designation, @Department);";
    IDbConnection connection = null;

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        connection.Query<Employee>(output_query, parameters);
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

However, I was not able to find the usage of parametrized queries of .NET with GridDB. I made the same function `addEmployee(Employee emp)` as follows:

```cs
public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    using (GSGrid store = new GSGrid("myCluster"))
    {
        using (GSTimeSeries<Employee> employeeContainer = store.GetTimeSeries<Employee>("EmployeeContainer"))
        {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                Name = emp.Name,
                Designation = emp.Designation,
                Department = emp.Department
            };
            employeeContainer.Put(newEmployee);
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, I need to know if GridDB offers some built-in features to help safeguard the data from injection attacks and mitigate the risk of injection vulnerabilities.

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Looks like it already does that for you, as the values are passed inside objects.

Comment: Side note: if you are using Dapper, you should use `connection.Execute` for a straight insert, not `connection.Query` (which needs to be disposed). And you don't need to open the conenction manually. You certainly don't need to check if a new connection is not open, of course it isn't as you just created it.